# gradle docker file to build jars

Tags: docker, gradle, docker-compose, build.gradle

i need advice what to include in docker file to build the jar before build docker image.

**originally, i am using this test.bat file to build the jar**

now i need to change this way, to use docker compose instead.

```html
CALL gradlew build 

rem docker build test-query/. -t testquery

rem docker run --name testquery -dit -p 8002:8002 --network lsvc --restart=unless-stopped testquery

rem docker build test-command/. -t testcommand

rem docker run --name testcommand -dit -p 8008:8008 --network lsvc --restart=unless-stopped testcommand
```

the Docker File , i modified to download gradle docker then build file

```html
FROM gradle:4.7.0-jdk8-alpine AS build
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /test-command/src
ADD --chown=gradle . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN gradle build test-query/. -t testquery
RUN gradle build test-command/. -t testcommand

FROM ubuntu
FROM openjdk:8-alpine
WORKDIR /app
VOLUME ["/app"]
COPY test-command/build/libs/*.jar /app/test-command.jar
COPY test-command/docker/startup.sh /app/startup.sh
#RUN sh -c 'touch /app/test-command.jar'
RUN chmod +x /app/startup.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/test-command.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/app/startup.sh"]
```

the startup.sh

```html
#!/bin/sh
sleep 150; java -jar /app/test-command.jar
```

error when docker-compose up

```html
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'test'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt']
   > Could not create an instance of type io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.extensions.DetektExtension_Decorated.
      > org.gradle.api.file.ProjectLayout.configurableFiles([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/gradle/api/file/ConfigurableFileCollection;

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of the `io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt` plugin you are using is not compatible with the older Gradle version 4.7 you are using. I assume you have already tested the Gradle build outside docker, so you are probably just using a wrong version of Gradle for Docker. See if you can upgrade it to either 5.x or 6.x (generally, the newer the better).

Otherwise, you will either have to downgrade the plugin (though I don't know what version dropped support for Gradle 4.7), or you have to find a replacement that works with the older version.

Comment: is the plugin part of "FROM gradle:4.3-jdk-alpine" ? yup, the tested outside docker and jars build successfully.